# Can a function return a type?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there was any way to do something like this in C++:

```cpp
$(some typename) func() {
    if (/*condition*/) return int;
    else return bool;
}
```

Edit: I think I wasn't clear enough. I was wondering if you could say something like this: `func() var = /*something*/`. Basically, the function is returning something like `int` or `bool` (the type, not a value of that type).

Comment: If your set of possible return types is limited you could use `std::variant`. In this case, `std::variant<int, bool>`. But you may find that actually using your function and its return value will be trickier than you might expect.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. I was wondering if you could say something like this:
func() var = /*something*/.
Basically, the function is returning something like int or bool (the type, not a value of that type).

Comment: What do you want to use this for? There is probably some way to achieve what you actually want to do. Could you please clarify why you want this?

Comment: For example, if I had a pointer to a certain polymorphic type and I wanted to know which template function I should use to evaluate it.

Comment: There are techniques for type mapping at compile time. You need to say what it is that you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: @dantheking-crypto That sounds like a job for a virtual function, that's what they're for.

Comment: @dantheking-crypto Stop adding essential information in your comments please. [Edit] your question instead, or even better write a clear question and explain your specific problem from the start.

Comment: if you explain how you would use it, then maybe we can show you a way to achieve that. The code you posted cannot be made to work, but what you actually want to achieve is unclear

Comment: You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the actual problem you want to solve instead of solution you think could be applied.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that isn't essential information though. All the required info to answer this question is already in the original question

Comment: @Fuad We can agree to disagree.

Comment: you can look at [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) for an example of selecting between two types. It isn't a function though.

Comment: It very much depends on whether your `/* condition */` is or isn't resolvable at compile time. Please, specify.

Comment: @dantheking-crypto It's good that you edit the question, but your still not giving enough information. What you ask can probably be done... but that depends on how you are planning to use `func()` in your example. If it was as simple always returning the same type you could just use a type alias. But It seems to me you have some other idea on how to use this `func` idea, and before you explain what that is giving you the right answer is close to impossible.

Comment: I guess the answer is correct. There's no way to write a function which returns *type* rather than an object, it's done with templates instead. But how to do that is entirely diffferent matter, I suggest getting [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on that topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function cannot choose which type to return at runtime; it must have a definite return type at compile time. What you can use instead is a template with a member type. You will need to use template metaprogramming for this. As an example, here is an adapter template that makes a type `T` into its const pointer form:

```
template <typename T>
struct make_const_ptr {
    using type = const T*;
};

template <typename>
using make_const_ptr_t<T> = typename make_const_ptr<T>::type
```

This is essentially a "function" that returns a type, in the sense that you can "call" it by writing `make_const_ptr_t<T>`. You can do a bunch more operations on types using template metaprogramming: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-metaprogramming-in-c/ .

Plus, you said in your comments that you wanted to use this to choose which template function to use on a polymorphic type. An even better way to do this is to use a virtual function; doing different things for different polymorphic types is the whole point of virtual functions:

```
template <typename T>
void template_function(const T& obj) {
    // ...
}

class Base {
    // ...
    virtual void do_template_function() = 0;
};

class D : public Base {
    virtual void do_template_function() {
        template_function<D>(*this);
    }
};

class E : public Base {
    virtual void do_template_function() {
        template_function<E>(*this);
    }
};

void f(Base* obj) {
    // ...
    obj->do_template_function();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i dont understand how this answers the question, but I also don't understand the question...

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm explaining how you can write a "function" that returns a type, as the OP is asking. Of course this is not an actual function but acts like a function in the way the OP wants.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 You can't differentiate return types via templates, you'll need a reference parameter for output instead. And please don't provide links to Geeks-for-Geeks  here. This site is notorious for all kind of mis- and half-informed problem _"solutions"_.

Comment: OPs code has a condition that is evaluated at runtime in the example. I wouldn't know how this fits in here

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not trying to differentiate return types, though. I explained to the OP how to write a compile-time "function" that returns a type, not an object.

Comment: @idclev463035818 OP's code does not necessarily have a run-time condition, it can be an expression based on compile-time constants. Besides I'm not using OP's code, I'm explaining how what they want can be accomplished via a different technique.

Comment: No point in guessing what OP wants, let him clarify his question instead.

Comment: i know that there is a way to interpret the question that makes your answer kind of ok. I am trying to tell you that this isnt the only interpretation ;)

Comment: As far as I understand the edit, OP wants a function that returns a type rather an object, and in this meaning the answer is correct. I don't see any other possible meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cute library [Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hana/) that can be used for computations on types in C++ metaprogramming.

With Boost.Hana a function returning an object representing the C++ type could look like this:

```cpp
auto func()
{
   return hana::if_(
      /*constexpr condition*/,
      hana::type_c<int>,
      hana::type_c<bool>
   );
}
```